# The use of SlotSequence in If[#1 > #2, ##] &

Tags: functions, pure-function, sequence

The below function when applied to a list of two elements, will output the maximum between the two:

```
If[#1 > #2, ##] &
```

For example:

```
In[1] : If[#1 > #2, ##] & [22,21]
Out[1]: 22 

In[2] : If[#1 > #2, ##] & [21,22]
Out[2]: 22
```

However I don't really get what's the use of the ## here. In the first output, why isn't it return Sequence[22,21] instead? And in the second output, how does the function knows to return 22, when there isn't a return statement for false condition in the If function ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is simple: First, you really need to look up the documentation of `##`. It means "take all arguments". But more importantly, you can use the property that `a > b` stays unevaluated when neither true or false can be computed. So check this out:

```
If[#1 > #2, ##] &[a, b]
(* If[a > b, a, b] *)
```

Do you see how `##` converts this construct into a simple "if a>b then a else b"?

Furthermore, `Sequence[a,b,c]` is Mathematica's way of saying "a sequence of arguments that can be fed into a function". As you might know, it is not possible to evaluate the input `a,b,c` without error. For normal functions, which don't have the attribute `HoldAllComplete`, a `Sequence[...]` expression is always flattened out.

```
func[Sequence[a, b, c]]
(* func[a, b, c] *)
```

This is exactly what happened in your `If`. When you understand that

```
## &[22, 21]
(* Sequence[22, 21] *)
```

and you know it's turned into a real sequence (without the `Sequence` around it) when inside a function, you understand what happened in your case.

Comment: Since you explicitly mention `HoldAllComplete`, it might be worth mentioning `SequenceHold` as well

Answer (score 7):

To understand how the [`SlotSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) (`##`) works, use [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html)

```
Trace[If[#1 > #2, ##] &[22, 21]]
```

[image]

```
Trace[If[#1 > #2, ##] &[21, 22]]
```

[image]